# Linked list beginning insert

Tags: c, list, structure

I've been having a hard time figuring out this code:

```
typedef struct student_grade sg;

sg *first = NULL;
sg *renew = NULL;
sg *temp = NULL;

int num;
float g;
char classname[12], fn[STR_LENS], ln[STR_LENS];

printf("Enter the classname (without spaces): ");
scanf("%11s", classname);

printf ("Enter the student's name and their grade. Enter 0 0 0 to quit. \n(FirstLast ##.#): ");



num = scanf("%11s %11s %f", fn, ln, &g);

while (fn[0] != '0')
{
    if (num == 3)
    {
        renew = (sg*) malloc(sizeof(sg));

        strncpy(renew->first_name, fn, STR_LENS-1);
        strncpy(renew->last_name, ln, STR_LENS-1);
        renew->grade = g;
        renew->next = first; //next pointer to first
        first =  renew; //assign address of renew to first
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter the student's name and their grade.Enter 0 0 0 to quit\n(First Last ##.#): ");

    num = scanf("%11s %11s %f", fn, ln, &g);

}
```

Particularly, this part:

```
        renew = (sg*) malloc(sizeof(sg));

        strncpy(renew->first_name, fn, STR_LENS-1);
        strncpy(renew->last_name, ln, STR_LENS-1);
        renew->grade = g;
        renew->next = first; //next pointer to first
        first =  renew; //assign address of renew to first
```

The `renew` gets allocated for the structure, points to `first` pointer, which was initially NULL, and `first` is assigned the same address to `renew`, which then points to the address of `renew`. After the second loop, the same `renew` apparently gets cloned and also points to the address of `first` and then the address of `first` gets assigned the same address of the cloned `renew`.

None of it adds up.

Answer (score 0):

There's no cloning of `renew` taking place. Every iteration will allocate a new chunk of memory (that's what the `malloc` call is doing) and change the `renew` pointer to reference this new memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a loop adding new elements to the beginning of a linked list.

The very first `scanf` reads the classname, and that's it. Then, there's another `scanf` which stores first name, last name and grade into 3 variables, and then the `while` loop begins:

Every time the code allocates with `malloc` the space for a new element, then fills its 3 fields (you are not showing the definition of `struct student_grade`, but we can deduce that it has the fields `first_name`, `last_name` and `grade`) by copying into them the data that the user has inserted using `scanf`, and then there are 2 more lines dealing with the linked list: we are inserting at the beginning, which means that the new element will become the first one. So, `renew->next = first;` makes sure that the element after the one we are creating (which is not in the list yet!) is the *current* first (which will become the second one at the next line), and then with `first =  renew;` the program ensures that from now on the list will start from the element that we are adding.

At the end of the loop, the new `scanf` asks for the data about another student, which are stored in the same variables as before, so that at the next iteration of the loop they can be copied into the structure, and it goes on until the user inserts a 0.

There is no cloning here. Every time you call `malloc` you get a new block of memory, different from the previous one, and its address is temporarily stored in `renew`. Since `renew` is overwritten every time, and you don't want to lose it, you must make sure it's stored somewhere: the address of the first element is always stored in `first`, and each element stores a pointer (`next`) to the next one, so that no address is lost. `renew` isn't cloned every time; on the contrary, the variable is always the same, but its value (the address) changes every time.

Answer (score 0):

> After the second loop, the same 'renew' apparently gets cloned...

First of all `renew` is not cloned. A totally new memory space is allocated to it.

You want to add `renew` to the start of your list. A different pointer (`first`) points to the start of your list.

`renew->next = first;` - with this line you basically say that 'okay, from this point `renew` will be the first item in my list and its next item will be the actual `first`. Basically `renew` is my 0th item in my list.`

`first =  renew;` - you have `renew` pointer which points to the start of your list. You also want the `first` point to point to the start of the list. So the solution for this is to set the `first` pointer to point to the same memory location as `first` pointer does. Now you both of your pointer will point correctly to the first item in your list.

`renew` basically is used as an auxiliary pointer. It helps adding new items to the list. In the other hand `first` pointer is an important component of your list. Its job is to point to the first element in your list.